# Don`t understand why I can`t get an access to result in another class method

Tags: php

Here's my class. `getPosts` method returns an array , but I can't get an access to it in `proceedPosts`. When I'm trying to print it in browser it shows me an error that `$result` variable is not `defined`.

```
class myClass
    {
        public $myposts;

        public function getPosts()
        {
           $result =  $this->myposts = array('a','b','c');

            return $result;

        }

        public function handlePosts()
        {
            echo $result;
        }
    }

    $myObj = new myClass();
    $myObj->getPosts();
    $myObj-> handlePosts();
```

Can anybody explain me why? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first problem is `$result;` is not known in `handlePosts()` function second you trying to echo an array you must have `toString` so to make your code work try this :

```
    <?php

    class myClass
        {
            public $myposts;

            public function getPosts()
            {
               $result =  $this->myposts = array('a','b','c');

                return $result;

            }

            public function handlePosts()
            {
              var_dump($this->getPosts());
            }
        }

        $myObj = new myClass();

        $myObj-> handlePosts();

    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `$result` variable has been created in the `getPosts()` method, and only lives and exists in this method (or scope if you prefer).

The return you have made in this method would only have made sense if you had code following:

```
$result_from_get_post_method =  $myObj->getPosts();
```

If you want to make class-wide accessible variables, you will have to use `$this` in front of your variable name, like:

```
class myClass
{
    public $myposts;

    public $result;

    public function getPosts()
    {
       $this->result = $this->myposts = array('a','b','c');

        return $this->result;

    }

    public function handlePosts()
    {
        echo $this->result;
    }
}

$myObj = new myClass();
$result_of_method = $myObj->getPosts();
print($result_of_method); // prints result_of_method which contains array
print($myObj->result); // does the same as line above, by calling object variable
$myObj->handlePosts(); // echos the array
```